# Страница пользователя SO в резюме

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Некоторые пользователи в резюме начали указывать ссылку на страницу в SO для того, чтобы показать свои ответы и рейтинг. Некоторые работодатели охотно начали принимать это.

Есть ли среди нас люди, которым помог рейтинг на SO при собеседовании? 
Расскажите вашу историю.

Comment: Вроде помог сегодня, пока не ясно. Если возьмут — расскажу подробности )

Comment: Ник, в любом случае расскажи, даже если будет не успешно.

Comment: Если сидеть целый день и редактировать вопросы, то заработать можно в десятки раз больше чем на ответах. Поэтому не совсем понятно, как будет выглядеть два-три более менее ответа + 6000 рейтинга для работодателя. Я полгода здесь и не разу не видел голосов столько сколько у тех у кого за 15k+, у них в десятки раз больше что вообще не характерно для RUSO. Это означает только одно, они рейтинг себе накрутили когда это было ещё возможно. Так что если кто и смотрит на это, то только не совсем умный чел. Лично я бы не стал читать длинные ответы, когда лично мог бы задать вопросы.

Comment: @OlmerDale по достижению отметки в 2к репутации за правки перестают давать репутацию, так что на них "не пофармить". Насчет накрутки не знаю, но если вопрос (и корректный ответ к нему) полезен не только для автора, но и для других людей, сталкивающихся с такой же проблемой, то изредка кто-то да плюсует старые вопросы и ответы.

Comment: @OlmerDale я специально посмотрел историю участника с 25к репутацией,  и знаешь, у него максимум и 300 баллов нету. все по 20 баллов с среднем. а человек с 11 года старается и отвечает на вопросы. так что, если хорошо постараться, то заработать репутацию не сложно. со временем, за ответы годовалой давности люди люди голосуют, а автор получает репутацию

Comment: @SeniorAutomator посмотрите мою историю .. с другой стороны я не понимаю, чем плохо то, что голоуют за старые ответы, если они помогают решить проблему.

Comment: @OlmerDale что со мной не так? расскажите, как я кругил рейтинг, пока возможно за чуть более полтора года. Вы не думаете, что человек, способный написать длинный ответ, за который голосуют может и ответить на вопрос при личной беседе? По профилю SO можно еще до встречи решить, нужно ли вам вообще беседовать с человеком, который больше задает вопросы по соискательному профилю, чем отвечает на вопросы других

Comment: @pavlofff а я не говорил, что плохо голосовать за старые ответы. я говорю, что со временем эти старые ответы приносят репу

Comment: Взяли, просто пока нет времени написать ответ. ))

Comment: @pavlofff если человек задаёт много *хороших* вопросов, я бы взял такого. Это означает что он 1) быстро учится 2) хорошо вникает в тему. Но это только если вопросы реально хорошие, точные и интересные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin что насчет времени на ответ?

Comment: @Regent на выходных сяду и напишу. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin на каких именно выходных ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin присоединяюсь к вопросу о выходных)

Comment: @Regent ох, хорошо. Сегодня сяду писать. :)

Comment: @Regent две недели каждый день много пишу, причём на английском. Ощущение, что соответствующие участки мозга устали и не хотят работать на выходных. Пишу ответ — периодически сбиваюсь и начинаю писать на английском ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin суровая же работа вам, видимо, досталась, раз мозг так перегружен

Comment: @Regent очень интересная, но непривычная немного. На стеке-то можно писать в расслабленном режиме. Надоело или устал — отложил в сторону.

Answer (score 38):

Да, было дело разок. На одной из прошлых должностей. Когда по опыту работы я был от силы слабым миддлом или сильным джуниором.

В конце собеседования с менеджером я спросил, что там с моим решением тестового задания. И узнал, что, оказывается, **меня кто-то рекомендовал**, и спросить об этом нужно этого кого-то. Но **я понятия не имел, кто это мог бы быть**, т. к. других знакомых Ruby-разработчиков (а именно на эту должность меня брали) у меня не было на тот момент.

*Или я только думал, что не было...*

Это казалось невероятным ещё и потому, что это не они меня позвали, а я откликнулся на их вакансию. Инициатором собеседования был я, а не они.

Оказалось, у них работал один из завсегдатаев тегов [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) и [ruby-on-rails](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) на en.SO, который видел мои ответы и имел представление о том, что я умею. Я тоже неоднократно встречал его комментарии и ответы. Так и познакомились. Вышла спонтанная личная встреча двух активных участников отдельно взятого уголка StackOverflow.

А тестовое задание? Его так никто и не посмотрел. Впрочем, на него ушла пара часов, от силы.

Это не единственная занимательная случайность в моей карьере, но одна из наиболее невероятных.

Comment: вау! спасибо за историю!

Comment: @D-side  вы были бы готовы заэндорсить кандидата к себе на работу, основываясь на активности в [tag:ruby]?

Comment: @Nofate, на себя намекаешь? :-)

Comment: @Nofate зависит от активности, конечно. Но да. Хотя скорее не за саму активность, а за продемонстрированные таким образом знания или способность их находить.

Comment: Осталось понять, есть ли разница между enSO и ruSO для работодателя.

Comment: @alexolut, йес коз ю кэн демонстрейт юр ленгуадж скиллс тсру enSO

Comment: @alexolut, работодатель это обычно не какой-то абстрактный чувак, это вполне конкретный скажем тимлид которому валится на стол пачка резюме он бегло их смотрит и говорит "зовем болтать этого". HR которые эту пачку собирают - им обычно пофигу какой там so, главное hr видит что кандидат вовлечен в тему (если hr хороший) или пофигу вообще (если hr плохой). А у конкретного тимлида может быть свой набор домыслов. Типа "на so одни школьники". Или "на ru.so клево, я там всех знаю"

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму или такой вариант "на ru.so клево, я там всех знаю, одни школьники"

Comment: @alexolut представлю себя на месте работодателя. Тут несколько факторов. Утка дело говорит, ответы на enSO ещё и уровень английского показывают. Хотя и не очень надёжно, меня на enSO иногда правил настоящий перфекционист по части грамматики, спасибище ему. Потом, есть фактор интересности материала. На enSO сложных вопросов, на мой взгляд, больше. Количественно. Потому и больше шансов иметь там интересные ответы, а потому больше мотивации оценивать соискателя именно по профилю на enSO.

Comment: @alexolut Очевидно, что на enSO более представительная и квалифицированная аудитория. У российских программистов на ruSO довольно низкая квалификация. Это бросается в глаза. Что касается работы, то может так оказаться, что тот, кто вас интервьюрует сам еще даже до ruSO не дорос, а потому не будет вас брать на работу, чтобы не выглядеть блекло на вашем фоне. Россия - это страна по распилу бабла. Поэтому нужны не специалисты, а дешевая квалифицированная рабочая сила, которая ни на что претендовать не будет.

Answer (score 13):

Ко мне регулярно обращается хедхантеры на основании моей страницы из SO (и из enSO и из ruSO), правда я всех посылаю лесом, ибо я не девелопер, не айтишник и пока удается зарабатывать хлеб насущным другим.

Comment: Вы совсем отошли от it, или работаете в какой то смежной сфере?

Comment: Я в перпендикулярной сфере, правда, хорошее знание IT мне всегда большое подспорье в работе.

Comment: Я вот тоже переодически получаю предложения из-за активности на этом ресурсе, но по разным причинам вынужден их отклонять :)

Comment: У вас профиль на SO как-то связан с вашими контактами? Или вам пишут через сам SO (их раздел с работой)?

Answer (score 11):

Расскажу вам широко известный в узких кругах секрет: существуют программные средства для хедхантеров, которые собирают воедино профили на различных сайтах. Если у вас на Stack Overflow ссылка на профиль на GitHub, а в профиле на LinkedIn ссылка на тот же GitHub, или же вы палите публично свой адрес электронной почты на разных сайтах, то эти программы соберут все ваши профили воедино, даже если они все не слишком идеально пролинкованы.

Одно из таких программных средств живёт в аддонах Хрома, оно позволяет, зайдя на любой из поддерживаемых сайтов в чей-нибудь профиль, увидеть ссылки на все профили на других сайтах. Вас уже посчитали.

Работа в офисе меня на данный момент не интересует, поэтому похвастаться устройством на работу за счёт 20К репы на двух программистских сайтах не могу, но меня через что-то подобное уже находили.

Уж не знаю, насколько полезными будут конкретные значения репы, сложность вопросов и тому подобное, но если вы светитесь на этих сайтах, и ваш профиль идентифицируем (вы оставляете контакты и/или ссылаетесь на другие сайты), то это позволяет вам появляться на радарах охотников за головами.

---

P. S. Если меня на собеседовании спросят, какого лешего я припёрся устраиваться, хотя я не разбираюсь в какой-то там конкретной технологии, указанной в требованиях, то буду использовать SO как аргумент: смотрите, я могу отвечать на вопросы по темам, которые вижу в первый раз.

Answer (score 2):

Не то, чтобы прям помогло, но в ~90% случаев, когда мне приходят предложения как специалиста по Android, то пишут про мой "большой рейтинг на ruSO". И это при условии, что я в резюме никогда ссылку на свой SO профиль не указывал.

Радует, что сейчас HR смотрят на публичные профили (SO, github, etc).

Я в курсе про автоматические тулзы для этого, но, по крайней мере, они не просто на циферки смотрят, а чекают по каким меткам наиболее активен и т.п.