# Зачем нужна репутация на Stack Overflow?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Совсем недавно *(относительно)* я начал активно помогать начинающим программистам на данной платформе. Я не задумывался об очках репутации, а также о других нюансах данного ресурса. За последние несколько дней я попал в 3% самых активных участников недели.

На этом моменте я решил задуматься — а что вообще такое "репутация" и зачем она нужна. На свой ответ я смог найти только одно объяснение — это признание *(своего рода)* в узком сообществе. Но всё ли это? Хотелось бы узнать, может я просто ещё *новенький* здесь и не всё понимаю?

Comment: Вообще в справке это написано. Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation . Да и вообще справку поюзайте, там много ответов уже есть

Comment: Репутация - признание в узком сообществе, постепенный доступ к привилегиям данного сообщества (правка, удаление, восстановление, защита вопросов, аналитика сообщества). Помимо этого можно получить признание и со стороны работодателя (мне удалось найти заказчика на проекты благодаря своим ответам) и со стороны товарищей. Но процентов 90 это действительно психология. Положительные эмоции от положительных голосов за ваши вопросы\ответы. Одобрение вашей работы.

Comment: А еще к Новому Году тут раздают всякие смешные шапки, которые можно "надевать" на свою аватарку! Все это стимулирует заходить сюда чаще, "участвовать в жизни сообщества"))

Comment: @HamSter Ну раз шапки раздают, тогда да, понимаю)))

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, =)))) ну это так) Информация по сообществу для нового участника)

Comment: Чтобы наниматели [хантили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4621/204271).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хоть у меня всего 645 за активных 9 дней пользования, лучше я думаю и правда в резюме указать... спасибо, натолкнули на мысль об этом.

Comment: Репутация прямо пропорциональна количеству усилий, которое вы вкладываете в сообщество (не обязательно даже ответами - до 2к репутация даётся за правки например), так что если вы сидите на so в рабочее время и набираете много репутации - то не факт, что это в глазах работодателя только лишь плюс ;)

Comment: @AK проблема в том, что у меня нет работы, я всего 3-й месяц изучаю все это( поэтому у меня точно есть время уделять внимание данному сообществу)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4622/209435) рассказ о том, как репутация помогла устроиться на работу

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Это фича, которая эксплуатирует особенности человеческой психологии. Если вкратце, то люди - существа социальные, при малейшей возможности выстраиваются в иерархию. Репутация дает что-то вроде социального статуса в сообществе. "Вот у него много репутации, наверно, он очень умный, к нему надо прислушиваться, а вот у этого мало, кто он вообще такой?" Человек с большей репутацией подсознательно воспринимается как высокоранговый (в данном сообществе, конечно же).
Здесь это свойство психики поставлено "на службу обществу". Механика такова, что вы получаете репутацию за помощь тем, кому она нужна. Подсознание вам говорит - "нужно заработать побольше репутации", после чего сознание включается и начинает анализировать способы ее получения.
Самое интересное, что это действует даже на тех, кто понимает, как это работает.

Конечно, все люди разные, у кого-то это стремление сильнее выражено, у кого-то слабее. Ну у кого слабее и кому неинтересно фармить репутацию - те здесь не сидят.

Comment: Красиво написал, +1

Comment: Эм.. И ни слова пор то, что даёт репутация при пользовании сайтом :(

Comment: @Qwertiy с определённого значения — ничего не даёт

Comment: @Qwertiy "Я художник, я так вижу этот мир" (с)

Comment: @älёxölüt, ты про 10К или про полный набор?

Comment: @Qwertiy про 25к