# Профиль и резюме

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

У каждого свой смысл существования.... Кто-то отвечает для репы, но репа - это не сама цель. Я пришел сюда, чтобы улучшать знания, в некоторой мере помогать людям.

Как думаете, есть ли смысл кидать ссылку на мой профиль, если летом буду претендовать на `Java Junior Developer`?

Смысл в том, чтобы это не выглядела, как вот моя детская фотография с детского сада, где я был быстрее всех...

Comment: Это "не сама цель"? А "сама"  что?

Comment: @Igor, цель же.

Comment: 1. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4621/178988 2. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2423/178988

Comment: Я наоборот, стараюсь чтобы мои будущие работадатели не смогли найти меня на СО. Потому что они увидят какие вопросы я задавал-задаю.

Comment: Я как-то провернул подобное. Мне сказали (на собеседовании, позже), что личные профили на сайтах Q/A указывать не надо, только CV, личный сайт (если там есть что показать в качестве готового продукта или нароботок) и профиль LinkedIn. Так что это больше для собственного развития :( Но если это так важно, то можно схитрить, добавив профиль на свой сайт, на который работодатели зайдут и невольно глянут что тут :)

Comment: @AntonSorokin если вы хотите скрыть свой профиль тут, почему у вас есть ссылки на свои остальные профили?

Comment: @michael_best ссылки на профили из SO, а на SO ссылок нет. Тем более, всякие linkedlist`ы смотрят hr`ы, а они скорее всего вопросы не будут смотреть/не поймут.